# checkbox not checked in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I have a form

```
<%= nested_form_for @parent do |p| %>
  <%= p.fields_for :child do |c| %>
    <%= c.check_box :boolean_field %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

why this check box is not checked when I want to edit a parent record while it is already c.boolean field is set to true and I can see value of text box is set to 1. How can I over come I tried a lot now its annoying me.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= c.check_box :boolean_field, :checked => true %>` should work.

Comment: what do you see in your inspect element.

Comment: seeing a value=1 has nothing to do with checked, It should be something like checked="checked" or true or just checked. try editing the html in your inspect element and putting checked="checked"

Comment: I have tried this also but same result when i add attribute in inspect checked='checked'

Comment: I don't know how that is possible it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/399fcb4y/

Comment: you will not believe what kind of mistake is this see my my answer thanks a lot for your attention I am going to up vote for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
<%= c.check_box :boolean_field, :checked => @parent.boolean_field %>
```

Answer (score 0):

damn mistake some one write this method in a js file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked')
});
```

and its a silly mistake I just removed this and it is working now.